# How do I make sure API calls returns data in order the request are sent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, react-redux

I have to make an API call asking for data whenever a user types something in a text box. The payload of that API call is what the user types. Now I want to preserve the order for the response too, but without making these calls synchronous as it is going to hang up the UI.

Right now what is happening is sometimes, the third call returns faster than the 1st call, but I want data in order of the request they are sent.

```
    handleChange(e)
    {
      apiCall(e.target.value)
    }
```

Whenever user types into the search box (html input field), handleChange is called. Suppose user types *a*, an api call is made with payload *a*. Now when user types *n*, an api call us made with payload *an*.

The problem that I'm having is that sometimes the second call returns the data faster than the first, but I want the order of the requests to be preserved in response as well without making these calls synchronous.

Comment: You can't.  You need to write your code in a way that can cope with the api calls returning in the order they return in.  For the case you're talking about you need to ignore the results of older calls because they've been replaced by newer ones, so could keep track on the client side of the most recent search, and ignore any API responses that don't match it; or throttle requests with debounce so the situation never arises in the first place.

Comment: One other thing you should look into is how to "debounce" the requests in order to give user a bit of time to type each letter

Comment: This is an XY problem. What you _really_ want is to throttle or debounce the `handleChange()` function so that a certain timeout has passed before you make the apiCall. This will not only make the UX better, but also reduces unnecessary calls to the server when the user is typing quickly: which will also solve your race condition.

Comment: The only reason I can think of where you should care about order is when your subsequent requests rely on data from a previous one... in which case I suggest looking at [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: The suggestions above about debouncing are wise because of the optimization they provide. In addition, you can also queue your requests and then resolve and use them in order. You might want to search for "promise queue".